# Regex for 'attr=value' style input

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have to get an input value in `attr=value` format. 
Something like `name=John` or `surname=Doe`. The string could contain number but no symbol other then `=` is allowed. 
Now, I need to validate the field in Javascript. I have already got a regex, which goes something like this `/[a-zA-Z0-9]+[=]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+/`. Its working fine. However, I feel like there might be a better regex to do this. Also, if user inputs something like `name=John-`, it allows it. Which should not be the case. If you guys could point me to the right direction, it would be great.

```js
var regexField = $('#regex-test'),
    RegEx = /[a-zA-Z0-9]+[=]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+/,
    isValid = function(element){
      return RegEx.test(element.val());
    };
$('#submit').click(function(e){
  if(isValid(regexField)){
    $('#err').hide();
    return;
  }
  $('#err').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="err" style="display:none">
    Please enter proper value!
</div>
<input type="text" id="regex-test" required/>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression is not far off from what you want. The reason it's allowing `name=John-` is because there is no anchoring to the ends of the string. It will also accept, for example, `#$%name=John-!?foo`. To anchor to the start use `^` and `$` for the end.

You don't need to put the `=` in a character class (as you've only got one option); and you definitely don't want to quantify it with `+` as you want exactly one (not one or more).

Finally, you can simplify it a little bit by making it case-insensitive, using the `i` flag.

Ultimately, this gives you:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+=[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

You can make it *even* simpler if you allow underscores in your attributes and values: then you can change `[a-z0-9]` to `\w`...but that's your call :)

Comment: That was great useful information, thank you so much. :)
Will help me in my future developments

Comment: Xophmeister, I think you forgot the A-Z bit here.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Nope: Read my comment about case-insensitivity

Comment: Ack.  Missed that.  Right on!

Comment: It is possible to make the regex even smaller like this: ``/^[^_\W]+=[^_\W]+$/i``. But I made this just out of fun, I do not advise anyone to use it like that because it is highly unreadable and very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

A version that allows whitespace around the `=`, and allows *only* whitespace after the `name=value` portion (and so disallows symbols at the end), would be:

```
RegEx = /\s*[a-z0-9]+\s*=\s*[a-z0-9]+\s*$/i
```

```js
var regexField = $('#regex-test'),
    RegEx = /\s*[a-z0-9]+\s*=\s*[a-z0-9]+\s*$/i,
    isValid = function(element){
      return RegEx.test(element.val());
    };
$('#submit').click(function(e){
  if(isValid(regexField)){
    $('#err').hide();
    return;
  }
  $('#err').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="err" style="display:none">
    Please enter proper value!
</div>
<input type="text" id="regex-test" required/>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```